# change marked.js image/link expression

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, codemirror

I need to change `marked.js` image expression.

The original expression is: `/^\!?\[(inside)\]\(href\)(\w*\S*)*/` --->  `![]()`

I need to get id of all images, so I need to transform the expression to get id value from this ----> `{>"id"<}![inside](href)`.

I tryed to change expression to something like this: `/^\{\>index\>\}\!?\[(inside)\]\(href\)(\w*\S*)*/`

And after thar I need to write an expression to get the "index" value of `{>index<}![inside](href)`

Examples for inside & href:

```
inline._inside = /(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]]|\](?=[^\[]*\]))*/;
inline._href = /\s*<?([\s\S]*?)>?(?:\s+['"]([\s\S]*?)['"])?\s*/;
inline._index = /(?:^\{\>[^\<\}]*\<\}|[^\{\>\<\}]|\<\}(?=[^\{\>]*\<\}))/; // I tryed this, but not works

//replacing

inline.link = replace(inline.link)
('inside', inline._inside)
('href', inline._href)
('index', inline._index)
();
```

Anyone can help me to build this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to obtain some data from a link that has some specific format, e.g. `{>"id"<}![inside](href)and_the_rest`.

So, the [best regex I can suggest](https://regex101.com/r/dT8pX7/1) for the moment can look like `{>([^<]*)<}\!?\[([^]]+)\]\(([^)]*)\)(\w*\S*)*`. It assumes you have "id" inside `>` and `<`, "inside" is inside `[` and `]`, and "href" is inside `(` and `)` one right after another.

```js
function FindValues(str) {
  var re = /\{\>([^<]*)\<\}\!?\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]*)\)(\w*\S*)*/; 
  var m;

  if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) 
  {
     return [m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]];  
  }
}
  
var vls = FindValues('{>"id"<}![inside](href)and_the_rest');
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "ID: " +vls[0] + "<br>INSIDE: " + vls[1] + "<br>HREF: " + vls[2] + "<br>REST: " + vls[3];
```

```html
<div id='id'/>
```

Comment: Hello, I have only one problem with link's `[text](http://example.com)`. 
Example of string: 
Original regexp returns me that: `["[text](http://example.com)", "text", "http://example.com", undefined, index: 0, input: "[text](http://example.com) and after"]`.

With that regexp .exec terurns: `["[text](http://example.com)", undefined, undefined, "text", "http://example.com", undefined, index: 17, input: "some text before [text](http://example.com) and after"]`
I need to get "input" without "some text before", can you help me with that please?

Comment: Could you provide an exact input string? I do not see "input", nor "some text before" in `[text](http://example.com)`.